# could not load file or assembly 'quickfix_net.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, quickfix

(Let me apologize first and say I have researched this question heavily and I'm aware there is much discussion about it and I believe I have tried most if not all of the suggestions without luck so far - any help greatly appreciated)  I will try to summarize this but I understand I will likely have to fill in some more details as you request.  Please be patient with me.

I have created two C# programs using VS2017.  Both run in my development environment (Win 10) but only the first runs in my production environment (Windows server 2012 R2).  The second gets the error shown in the title.  They are both FIX-protocol-using trading programs which fundamentally use the same code base that links the FIX libraries including quickfix_net.dll.

I tried using dependency tracker and there are errors but they are identical between the program that is working and the one that isn't.

I used fuslogvw but it apparently shows that the dll in question is loaded successfully.

The csproj for both programs (working and non-working) shows the same relative path to pull in the dll and it is in the same location in both trees.

The only suspicious thing I see is that the first program created sometime earlier shows a target architecture of "mixed platforms" but this option was not available when the second program was created which uses "any CPU". (I tried using both x86 and "Any CPU" for the failing one with no luck.

I am basically tapped of ideas after several days.  If anyone has an idea, please tell me what code/log-files/configs or whatever you may want to see.  Appreciate greatly any help in advance....thanks.

> > addition - to simplify the problem description, this program starts fine and finds and loads the dll on any Windows 10 desktop machine.  It fails on any server-based windows OS (2012/16 etc.) running on a VPS.  I just need to get this thing running remotely.  Really would appreciate any help thanks.
> >
> > more info - I tried setting up a VM on Azure which has a full win 10 desktop install like on my laptop and I still get the failure to load the dll.  Truly baffling...
> >
> > Below is the output from fuslogvw.exe.  As you can see, the assembly load appears to succeed
>
> ```
> * Assembly Binder Log Entry  (5/10/2019 @ 7:38:37 AM) *
> ```
>
> The operation was successful. Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation
> completed successfully.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
> executable 
> C:\Trading\Trailer\Trailer\Trailer\bin\x86\Release\Trailer.exe
> --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = quickfix_net, Version=1.0.3748.13264, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null 
> (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
> file:///C:/Trading/Trailer/Trailer/Trailer/bin/x86/Release/ LOG:
> Initial PrivatePath = NULL LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL LOG: Cache Base =
> NULL LOG: AppName = Trailer.exe Calling assembly : FIXWrapper,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
> === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
> C:\Trading\Trailer\Trailer\Trailer\bin\x86\Release\Trailer.exe.Config
> LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
> file from
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
> LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
> custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
> download of new URL
> file:///C:/Trading/Trailer/Trailer/Trailer/bin/x86/Release/quickfix_net.DLL.
> LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file:
> C:\Trading\Trailer\Trailer\Trailer\bin\x86\Release\quickfix_net.dll
> LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase. LOG: Assembly Name is:
> quickfix_net, Version=1.0.3748.13264, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from
> C:\Trading\Trailer\Trailer\Trailer\bin\x86\Release\quickfix_net.dll.
> LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could comment, but I can only post answers until I get enough points. I have had similar issues when using third party libraries. I found that using any cpu can cause issues if the library is 32 bit. In the properties page for the project check to see if the prefer 32 bit flag is checked under the build tab.

Comment: That's a good thought @Versex however I checked and can see that the "Prefer 32-bit" option is grayed out (disabled) in both cases (the working program and the one that doesn't work).  Are you saying that you had to check this option to make the dll load properly in your case?

Comment: That is correct. When running any cpu on a 64 bit system, it will cause that error while using 32 bit dlls. This occurred for me when I had it set to any cpu.

Comment: Could you provide any help on why the 32-bit option is greyed out?

Comment: Do you have any cpu selected? This needs to be selected for the option to become available

Comment: Yes, I select "Any CPU" but the "Prefer 32-bit" option remains disabled

Comment: After trying several things, I was able to enable the "prefer 32-bit" option but unfortunately it did not resolve the problem.